# I keept getting a java.math.bigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long iafter trying to connect

Tags: java, mysql

I've been trying to connect MySQL to Java for a while now but I keep getting this error:
[image: error]

Here's my **Admin Properties** for the MySQL Server:

[image]

I'm using MySQL connector v8.0.19 and I tried using the v5 but still got the same error.

Comment: Similar : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52902471/2711811

Comment: I saw that and I tried following his steps but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change another MySQL server version, I encounter a bug causing MySQL Server 8.0.17 cannot connect via various of the connector inside Netbeans IDE.

Below are MySQL connector failed to connect MySQL server 8.0.17, which is showing exception of "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long":

```
mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-sources.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.48-bin.jar
mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar
mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar
mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar
```

End up I using MySQL server 5.7.26, which development purpose is okay, can connect using any of the connector without any issue.